# Simplest GAE access for apps marked internal?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

There are now many ways to control access to a GAE Web App. Simply marking the app as "Internal" versus "External" on the OAuth consent screen doesn't seem to exclude access by other users. Adding the IAP-Web-App-Engine-app seems to limit the app to principles - of which I am listed and am the project owner and app engine admin, but it says "You Don't Have Access." What am I missing here?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Can you explain the issue in details? Can you tell how did you set up `IAP` (steps followed) for `App Engine`?